# Seeking the generating function of $\left( 1+\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon x \right)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, legendre-functions

Many physical problems can be effectively solved using series expansions, such as the utilization of Legendre polynomials. Consider the function $\left( 1+\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon x \right)^\frac{1}{2}$. It can be readily demonstrated that this function can be represented as a series expansion involving Legendre polynomials:

$$
\frac{1}{\left( 1+\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon x \right)^\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \epsilon^n P_n(x) \, , 
$$

Here, $P_n(x)$ denotes the Legendre polynomial of order $n$. The expansion proves to be a valuable tool for solving problems related to this function.

Now, let's explore the possibility of finding a similar expansion for the function $f(x,\epsilon) = \left( 1+\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon x \right)^{-1}$. Although a Taylor expansion can be employed to obtain an initial insight:

$$
f(x,\epsilon) = 1 + 2x\epsilon + \left( 4x^2-1\right)\epsilon^2 + \dots \, ,
$$
a more general expression does not readily come to mind. Thus, I seek assistance in establishing an analogous expansion in terms of familiar functions for $f(x,\epsilon) = \left( 1+\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon x \right)^{-1}$. Any help or insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: dont call both fuctions $f$, also note that the second is the square of the first

Comment: Have you tried writing $f$ as a double sum involving Legendre polynomials of order $n$ and $m$?

Comment: That sounds like a great suggestion. Then $f(x,\epsilon) = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} \epsilon^{m+n} P_n(x) P_m(x)$. I thought about it but just wondering whether a simple expression potentially with a single sum can be obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1-2\epsilon \cos \theta+\epsilon^2)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin \theta}\epsilon^n...$$

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Best greetings to Toulouse!